# Getting values from a nested array

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I've read a couple of Stack overflow posts, but nothing that applies to the data layer in Meteor.
I made a mistake by nesting some data and now I'm struggling to find the light. Please help me understand what is going on.

```
    {
      _id: 1,
       ownerId: 03dk08xk30j,
       ....
       path: [
               {id: 1, name: 'filename.jpg', path: 'http://www.meteor.com/logo.png", path: '/home/user/documents/uploads/filename.jpg"},
               {id: 2, name: 'filename2.jpg', url: 'http://www.meteor.com/logo2.png", path: '/home/user/documents/uploads/filename2.jpg"}
    ]

    }
```

I have a renderAttachments() function that I want to return all of the name/path/url data fields.

```
renderAttachments() {
    return this.data.res.path.map((value) => {
   return <Attachment key={value._id} value={value} />;
   });
 },
```

I give it a prop

```
Attachment = React.createClass({
 render() {
  return (
   <div>{this.props.value.name}</div>
    )
   }
  });
```

React returns complaining that this.data.res.path is undefined. So, I guess the data isn't ready? Or I need the correct path?

I can pull out the path if I use JSON notation in the Attachment component. And use this.data.res.. instead of this.data.res.path.map...but that's not an option!

Please help!

Comment: How did you try "JSON notation in the Attachment component" ?

Comment: this.data.res.path[0].name

Comment: Can you post where `this.data` is getting bound?

Comment: getMeteorData() { Meteor.subscribe('purchases", this.props._id) return { res: Purchases.find().fetch() }  // Meteor.publish("purchases", function (id) {
    return Purchases.find(id);